# Выборка последней записи из массива

Tags: php

Ребят привет, вопрос. нужно выбрать последнюю запись из массива. 
Сейчас это работает так, есть список расписания. выводится так:

13:00 - событие 1 //выводится прошедшее событие относительно текущего времени
14:00 - событие 2 //текущее событие которое идет сейчас 
15:00 - событие 3 //событие которое произойдет после текущего события что идет сейчас

Собственно у меня проблема вот в чем, прошедшее событие выводится всегда именно так:

07:00 - событие 1 //почему-то выводит всегда именно первую запись, а именно 7 часов утра, хотя по идее должно выводить 13:00
14:00 - событие 2 //текущее событие которое идет сейчас 
15:00 - событие 3 // след. событие

вот мой пример:

```
for ($l = 0; $l < 1; $l++) {
```

.......
}

Comment: покажите пример массива и что нужно получить

Comment: идет парсинг расписания с другого сайта, полученые данные я вывожу в массив. Именно данный код должен выводить 1 запись до текущего события, текущее событие вывожу тоже через for сравнивая с текущим временем.

Comment: так получаю событие которое идет в данный момент: for ($l = 0; $l < count($time[1]); $l++)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пройти по массиву циклом, сравнивая значение в ключе с текущим временем:

```
$array = [
    '13:00' => 'событие 1',
    '14:00' => 'событие 2',
    '15:00' => 'событие 3'
];

$current_time = (new DateTime)->format('H:i');

foreach ($array as $time => $event) {
    $current_time <= $time ?: $temp[] = $event;
}

echo end($temp);
```

Результат:

```
событие 2
```

Comment: @VladVlad8 я отредактировал ответ с учётом ваших комментариев.